# How do I link multiple libraries in a Firebreath plugin?

Tags: dll, cmake, static-libraries, firebreath

Does anyone know where I can find a Firebreath sample (either Mac OS X or Windows) that illustrates how to create a plugin that includes 1 or more other libraries (.DLLs or .SOs) that each rely on other sub-projects built as static libraries (LIBs)?

For example, let's say that the Firebreath plugin is called PluginA, and that PluginA calls methods from DLL_B and DLL_C. DLL_B and DLL_C are C++ projects. DLL_B calls methods from another project called LIB_D, and DLL_C calls methods from a project called DLL_E.

Therefore, the final package should contain the following files:

```
PluginA.dll
DLL_B.dll (which also incorporates LIB_D)
DLL_C.dll
DLL_E.dll
```

I am currently forced to dump all source files in the pluginA solution, but this is just a bottleneck (for example I cannot call libraries written in other languages, such as Objective-C on Mac OS X).

I tried following the samples on Firebreath, but couldn't get them to work, and I found no samples from other users that claimed they were able to get it to work. I tried using CMAKE, and also running the solutions directly from X-Code, but the end result was the same (received linking errors, after deployment DLL_C couldn't find DLL_E etc.)

Any help would be appreciated - thank you,

Mihnea

Answer (score 1):

You're way overthinking this.

On windows:

- DLLs *don't* depend on a static library because if they did it would have been compiled in when they were built.
- DLLs that depend on another DLL generally just need that other DLL to be present in the same location or otherwise in the DLL search path.
- Those two things taken into consideration, all you need to do is locate the .lib file that either is the static library or goes with the .dll and add a `target_link_library` call for each one. [There is a page on firebreath.org that explains how to do this](http://www.firebreath.org/x/WoAT).

On linux it's about the same but using the normal rules for finding .so files.

Comment: Thanks @taxilian, I'll give this a try. As a side note, since each of my LIBs is a project (with source files), I don't want to pre-compile the LIBs in the DLL, because I would still need to debug each project, so my question was more on how to get CMAKE to automatically include all projects (whether they are DLLs or LIBs), so I can debug the projects easily. For example, I would be happy to have all of my sub-projects as static libraries and link them via CMAKE in the final Firebreath Plugin DLL, but so far I couldn't get that to work either (and I haven't seen any example that works either).

Comment: if you build all the subprojects in cmake then it's pretty straightforward; it's possible to define a dependency chain in cmake as well, though I don't know how off the top of my head.  That's really more a cmake question than a firebreath one. Just link to each library that you need; that's how I'd do it.